Quick Grid Formatting
Is there a way to format a string directly inside of quickgrid
I can get and display the information without any issue, I would just like to format the data to look clean inside of the table
<PropertyColumn Title="Phone Number:" Property="@(u => u.Phone)" />
<PropertyColumn Title="Phone Number:" Format="{0:###-###-####}" Property="@(u => u.Phone)" />
What I tried using earlier, it just deleted the Phone Property Column

I have Phone saved as the following inside of a DTO
[Required, MaxLength(11), DataType(DataType.PhoneNumber)]    
public string Phone { get; set; }
I did find out that the Format feature is an IFormattable Object
Quick Grid Format
I tried to create a PhoneFormatterClass and use that to pass user.Phone, and convert to an IEnumerable, then pass to the Format="@PhoneNumber"
This result was Ok, and didn't cause any errors, data was displayed, just not the format I was looking for
FormatPhoneNumber in Razor Page, ManageUsers
    private void FormatPhoneNumber(UserDTO user)
    {
        if(user.Phone != null)
            try
            {
                var phoneNumber = user.Phone;
                string formatNumber = PhoneFormatter.FormatPhoneNumber(phoneNumber);
                return;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _errorMessage = ex.Message;                
            }
        
    }

Here is the PhoneFormatter.cs File I was trying to use
 public class PhoneFormatter
 {
     public static string FormatPhoneNumber(IEnumerable<char> phoneNumber)
     {
         // Filter out non-digit characters
         var digits = phoneNumber.Where(char.IsDigit).ToArray();

         // Ensure we have exactly 10 digits
         if (digits.Length != 10)
         {
             throw new ArgumentException("Phone number must contain exactly 10 digits.");
         }

         // Format the phone number
         return $"({new string(digits.Take(3).ToArray())}) {new string(digits.Skip(3).Take(3).ToArray())}-{new string(digits.Skip(6).Take(4).ToArray())}";
     }
 }

Added Entire User Razor Page
<SectionContent SectionName="pageTitle">Manage Users</SectionContent>

<div class="card mb-3">
    <div class="card-header d-flex flex-row">
        <h5 class="flex-fill">Users</h5>
        <div class="px-1">
            <select class="form-select form-select-sm" onchange="OnPageSizeChanged">
                <option value="5">5</option>
                <option value="10">10</option>
                <option value="25">25</option>
                <option value="50">50</option>
                <option value="100">100</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        @*   <button class="btn btn-sm btn-info" @onclick="OnAddUser">Add New User</button> *@
    </div>
</div>


<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3 ms-auto mb-3">
        <label class="form-label"> Filter by Approved Status</label>
        <select class="form-control" @bind="_filter" @bind:after="OnFilterChangedAsync">
            @foreach (var f in Enum.GetValues<UserApprovedFilter>())
            {
                <option value="@f">@f</option>
            }
        </select>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="col-lg-12 control-section">
    <div class="content-wrapper">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="edddata">

                <DropDownListFieldSettings Text="Text" Value="Value"></DropDownListFieldSettings>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>


<div class="row">
    <QuickGrid ItemsProvider="_usersProvider" @ref="_grid" Pagination="_paginationState" Class="Table" ItemKey="@(u => u.Id)" >
        <PropertyColumn Title="Id:" Property="@(u => u.Id)" Sortable="true" InitialSortDirection="SortDirection.Ascending"/>
        <PropertyColumn Title="First Name:" Property="@(u => u.FirstName)" />
        <PropertyColumn Title="Last Name:" Property="@(u => u.LastName)" />
        <PropertyColumn Title="Phone Number:" Property="@(u => u.Phone)" />
        <PropertyColumn Title="Email:" Property="@(u => u.Email)"/>          
        <PropertyColumn Title="Address:" Property="@(u => u.Address)" />
        <PropertyColumn Title="City:" Property="@(u => u.City)" />
        <PropertyColumn Title="State:" Property="@(u => u.State)" />
        <PropertyColumn Title="Zip Code:" Property="@(u => u.Zip)" />
        <PropertyColumn Title="Role:" Property="@(u => u.Role)" Sortable="true">
            <ColumnOptions>
                <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" @bind="ShowRole" /> Show Role
                    <hr />
                    <button onclick="@OnFilterChangedAsync">Reset</button>
                </label>
            </ColumnOptions>
        </PropertyColumn>
        <TemplateColumn Title="Is Approved?">

            <div class="form-check form-switch">
                <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" checked="@(context.IsApproved)"
                role="switch" id="u_@context.Id" @onchange="() => OnUserApprovedToggleAsync(context)" />
                <label class="form-check-label" for="u_@context.Id">
                    @(context.IsApproved ? "Yes" : "No")
                </label>
            </div>
        </TemplateColumn>

    </QuickGrid>
    <Paginator State="_paginationState" />
</div>


@code {
    private const int DefaultPageSize = 10;

    private QuickGrid<UserDTO>? _grid;


    private string nameFilter = string.Empty;

    private GridItemsProvider<UserDTO> _usersProvider;

    private string? _role;

    private bool? ShowRole = null;

    private UserApprovedFilter _filter = UserApprovedFilter.All;

    private PaginationState _paginationState = new PaginationState { ItemsPerPage = DefaultPageSize };

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        _usersProvider = async request =>
        {
            AppState.ShowLoader("Fetching users, please standby.");
            var pagedResult = await UserAPI.GetUsersAsync(_filter, request.StartIndex, request.Count ?? DefaultPageSize);
            AppState.HideLoader();
            return GridItemsProviderResult.From(pagedResult.Records, pagedResult.TotalCount);
        };
    }

    private async Task UserRoleChangedAsync(UserDTO user)
    {
        
        _role = user.Role;
        _shouldReRender = false;
        AppState.ShowLoader("Updating user role, please standby.");
        await UserAPI.ChangeUserRoleAsync(user.Id);
        _shouldReRender = true;
        AppState.HideLoader();
    }

    private async Task OnUserApprovedToggleAsync(UserDTO user)
    {
        user.IsApproved = !user.IsApproved;
        _shouldReRender = false;
        AppState.ShowLoader("Updating status, please standby.");
        await UserAPI.ToggleUserApprovedStatusAsync(user.Id);
        _shouldReRender = true;
        AppState.HideLoader();
    }

    

    private bool _shouldReRender = true;

    protected override bool ShouldRender() => _shouldReRender;

    private async Task OnFilterChangedAsync()
    {

        if (_grid != null)
            await _grid.RefreshDataAsync();
    }


}

Here is the API Class
using Refit;

namespace .Web.APIs
{
    [Headers("Authorization: Bearer ")]
    public interface IUserAPI
    {
        [Get("/api/users")]
        Task<PagedResult<UserDTO>> GetUsersAsync(UserApprovedFilter approveType, int startIndex, int pageSize);

        [Get("/api/users")]
        Task<PagedResult<UserDTO>> GetUsersAsync(UserRole userRole);

        [Patch("/api/users/{userId}/change-role")]
        Task ChangeUserRoleAsync(int userId);

        [Patch("/api/users/{userId}/toggle-status")]
        Task ToggleUserApprovedStatusAsync(int userId);

    }
}

Error with adding Format section inside of the PropertyColumn :
crit: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Rendering.WebAssemblyRenderer[100]
      Unhandled exception rendering component: A 'Format' parameter was supplied, but the type 'System.String' does not implement 'System.IFormattable'.
System.InvalidOperationException: A 'Format' parameter was supplied, but the type 'System.String' does not implement 'System.IFormattable'.
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.QuickGrid.PropertyColumn`2[[xxxx.Shared.DTOs.Users.UserDTO, AceManager.Shared, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null],[System.String, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].OnParametersSet()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase.CallOnParametersSetAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase.SetParametersAsync(ParameterView parameters)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Rendering.ComponentState.SupplyCombinedParameters(ParameterView directAndCascadingParameters)

